# How to add geojson points to the map

Tags: javascript, angular, openlayers, geojson

I have an array of points all are in Geojson format. I would like to know how can add such points to the map.
I referred to some questions and some used the following

```
geojson.features
```

but in my case when I call `.features` I receive `undefined`. please see the following links

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282208/drawing-a-polygon-over-a-point-in-openlayers

[draw point on map given coordinates with openlayers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775622/draw-point-on-map-given-coordinates-with-openlayers)

Please let me know how to add geojson point to the map correctly.

**array of geojson points**:

```
["{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73648711211944,51.1144539430392]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73628689838002,51.1141803601161]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73648765865954,51.1141088970156]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.7368576747845,51.1141914104954]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73641043458919,51.1141123530415]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73655920234526,51.1144536412875]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73614395402386,51.1142745754592]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73642965248497,51.1141830888474]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73641750225145,51.1144305273589]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73671503777408,51.1141886499952]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73671498356252,51.1141886122033]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73657228945022,51.1141858496955]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73655926013517,51.1144536295152]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.7364332915611,51.1141086186341]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73642959244726,51.1141831229718]}", "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73688015139349,51.1142293782007]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geojsons contain only geometry, so you will need to read each from the array and create a Feature which can be displayed on the map.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
    html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
      
      var geojsons = [
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73648711211944,51.1144539430392]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73628689838002,51.1141803601161]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73648765865954,51.1141088970156]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.7368576747845,51.1141914104954]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73641043458919,51.1141123530415]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73655920234526,51.1144536412875]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73614395402386,51.1142745754592]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73642965248497,51.1141830888474]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73641750225145,51.1144305273589]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73671503777408,51.1141886499952]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73671498356252,51.1141886122033]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73657228945022,51.1141858496955]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73655926013517,51.1144536295152]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.7364332915611,51.1141086186341]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73642959244726,51.1141831229718]}",
        "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[6.73688015139349,51.1142293782007]}"
      ];

      var features = [];
      geojsons.forEach(function(geojson) {
        var geometry = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readGeometry(geojson, {
          dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
          featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()
        });
        features.push(new ol.Feature(geometry));
      });

      var source = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: features
      });

      map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 5,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'red'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: 'blue',
              width: 2
            })
          })
        })
      }));

      map.getView().fit(source.getExtent());
      map.getView().adjustZoom(-4);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will acknowledge on Monday or Tuesday.regards

Comment: would you please modify a little bit youe answer so that it shows how to add colors to the points? i checked the example in openlayers website but it is in java script, may be you can add color to points in more easy way

Comment: There are many ways you could style your points, I have added an example style.

Comment: is this answer is applicable and valid in case of inteneding to show polygons?or it is only for points.? i mean should i make a new question asking about how to show polygons in geojson in openlayers?

Comment: It would work with any geojson geometries in the array.  You would need separate styling for polygons and linestrings as image styles only work for points.